# Why is ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping needed

Tags: xml, spring, configuration, controller

I thought ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping was for mapping a url to a controller (after removing the Controller portion) but this doesnt seem to be the case with my example.

If I remove the "/navigation" mapping from the navigation controller (see below) then I get 404 errors.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

<bean name="navigationController" class="com.mvc.controller.NavigationController">
    <property name="methodNameResolver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.PropertiesMethodNameResolver">
            <property name="mappings">
                <props>
                   <prop key="/navigation/menu">menuHandler</prop>
                </props>
           </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In the code snippet above I need to pass the property key as /navigation/menu but I thought if the /navigation is mapped to the controller then I could get away with passing /menu otherwise what is the point of the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping?

I tried removing ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping but it is needed.

Can somebody explain what the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping is actually doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` is mapping:

`/navigation/* -> NavigationController.`

If you remove it, the NavigationController is never executed and lost any chances to map the url to a method.

The workflow is:

```
 DispatcherServlet -> ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping 
 -> NavigationController -> MethodNameResolver -> method
```

**Edit**

For example if you want to map "menu" directy to menuHandler method you could use the following MethodNameResolver

```
public class LastPathNameMethodResolver extends AbstractUrlMethodNameResolver {

    private Properties mappings;

    @Override
    protected String getHandlerMethodNameForUrlPath(String urlPath) {
        return mappings.getProperty(StringUtils.substringAfterLast(urlPath, "/"));
    }

    public Properties getMappings() {
        return mappings;
    }

    public void setMappings(Properties mappings) {
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }
```

Comment: Ok thank you for that its almost the answer I was after, there is one thing I am still unsure of but I think my original question was not clear enough. So if /navigation is mapped by ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping to NavigationController that is what I actually thought anyway. What I dont understand is why when I now want to map to a method inside NavigationController I still need the URL to be (for example) '/navigation/menu' and not '/menu' which is what I would have thought I could do.

Comment: When I was using annotations I annotated the class with a @RequestMapping for /navigation and then each method would have a further request mapping such as /menu. When I try to do <prop key="/menu">menuHandler</prop> then I get a 404 error.

Comment: Because NavigationController have no idea of how it become mapped. It simply match urls (from servlet path by default) to methods using a MethodNameResolver. You can use ant expressions or implement the MethodNameResolver

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought it might work in the same way as the annotation type config in that NavigationController knows its path its mapped to and so would the method name resolver. Thank you for explaining.